# Transposing data in MySql

Tags: mysql, transpose

How can I transpose information from a column into a row?

I have the following table:

```
Drop table if exists Example;
Create table Example
    (
    ID int,
    Group_ID int,
    Group_Name varchar(16)
    );
Insert into Example (ID, Group_ID, Group_Name)
    Values
    ('1','11', 'A'),
    ('1','21', 'K'),
    ('2','16', 'E'),
    ('2','6', 'Z')
    ;
Select * from Example;
```

And I want to split the information given in the field Group_ID and Group_Name for each ID. It should finally look like this:

```
Drop table if exists Solution;
Create table Solution
    (
    ID int,
    Group_ID_First_Entry int,
    Group_ID_Second_Entry int,
    Group_Name_First_Entry varchar(16),
    Group_Name_Second_Entry varchar(16)
    );

Insert into Solution (ID, Group_ID_First_Entry, Group_ID_Second_Entry, Group_Name_First_Entry, Group_Name_Second_Entry)
    Values
    ('1','11', '21', 'A', 'K'),
    ('2','16', '6', 'E', 'Z')
    ;
Select * from Solution;
```

I tried to use something like 'Case when' but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!